# Find the values of resistance R and inductance L in the R-L-C circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]

I'm not really sure how is the current, represented,
usually it was represented as the positive OX axis and the voltage (potential difference) was between -90 and 90.

Is the current -35 below the voltage that is on the OX axis?

Comment: Yes. Since the phase of the voltage is not explicitly mentioned, it can be assumed that it is the reference and hence aligned to the OX axis.

Comment: @AJN Could you convert your comment to an answer, please? That way the OP could accept your answer and we can have some closure for this question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since the phase of the voltage is not explicitly mentioned, it can be assumed that it is the reference and hence aligned to the OX axis.

The current phase is specified in the question. The question asks for the impedance to be found which requires voltage magnitude and phase also to be known / specified. This justifies the above assumption that the voltage phasor is the reference phasor to which the current is referenced to.